# HTML iframe - disable scroll in the first frame?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Currently I am using iframes to create tabular navigation for one module.

On module main page I have two tabs, inside one of those frames I have another two tabs after a single selection box. The content inside frames for 3rd and 4th tab will contain most of the content, that will get the frame to overflow. So.. what I want is to start the scroll bar not from 1st/2nd tab (or not first frames created) but from 3rd and 4th tab instead.

```
1st Tab| 2nd Tab
(SelectBox)
3rdTab | 4th Tab
(The rest of content)
```

Below is some code example (first frame):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        // create tab with td
    </tr>
    <tr>
        // create tab with td
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="newstabs" class="bg2" style="border-left:0px; border-right:0px; border-bottom:0px;">
    <iframe  src ="Download.asp" width="158" height="274" id="download3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="newstabs0" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; visibility: hidden; margin: 10px;">
    <iframe  src ="Download.asp" width="158" height="274" id="download2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>    
<div id="newstabs1" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; visibility: hidden; margin: 10px;">
    <iframe  src ="Upload.asp" width="158" height="274" id="upload" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

The `Download.asp` has similar iframe setup, which is where I want the scrolling to work, not from the main page.

How can I do this? Setting `scrolling="no"` in the main page's iframs disables scrolling on `Download.asp` page as well.

Comment: What happens if u give `<iframe  src ="Download.asp" width="158" height="274" id="download2" frameborder="0" scrolling = "no"></iframe>`

Comment: Or `style="overflow:hidden"`

Comment: I tried those both before. `style="overflow:hidden"` doesn't seem to work. And `scrolling = "no"` disables scrolling on the inner frame as well.

Comment: Could you provide your page url?